# Rewriting url facing issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

I am trying to convert this : `index.php?store=abc` to this : `index.php/abc`, eventually it would mean that if I live my website it will be like this : `www.mysite.com/abc`

But somehow I am trying `.htaccess` on wampserver but it doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{index.php} !-d
   RewriteCond %{index.php} !-f
   RewriteCond %{index.php} !-l
   RewriteCond %{index.php} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't work at all...

I am trying to check by this code

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['s']))
  {
     echo "working";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "not working";
  }
?>
```

Comment: something like : `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>` would do the trick no ? (sorry for formating, can't linebreak in comments). Check the cakephp way to do things, it's a nice method : [cakePHP 2.X url rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)

Comment: Didn't work that is why

Comment: What error do you have, what is your PHP code behind to process this ? We can help you if you put some more data :)

Comment: Check the code I am using simple code to try accessing it

Comment: How will php come to know there is a variable 's' in query string? Think about it.

Comment: then just do index.php?s=$1

Comment: Come on someone give me a proper code in answer. I tried but it doesn't take `abc.php/abc`